# How does GitHub Desktop launch straight from the browser? And how can I implement this?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, github, github-desktop

How does GitHub launch its GitHub Desktop application directly from the browser?

It works even when using Google Chrome. I thought that this was impossible outside of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Does it launch as soon as you visit a site or after you click a link? If you need to click a link check the format of the link. They might have simply registered their own protocol handler. An example for this would be [steam](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) as well.

Comment: @Seth Google chrome doesn't support custom protocols, I think that is only Internet Explorer that allows you to add a registry key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you register a custom protocl following the guide [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

Using a simple reg file that looks like the following you would register a custom protocol named `mytest:` that starts `C:\temp\test.bat` when its called.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mytest]
@="URL:mytest Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mytest\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mytest\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mytest\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\temp\\test.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Using the following content for `test.bat` you would get a cmd window that displays the argument and stays open:

```
echo %1%
pause
```

This works straight on your cmd, IE and Firefox. Chrome and Opera would give you a warning that you're about to start an application. This information is also available in this question: [Custom protocol handler in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome)

If you look further into it you will find that the github application registers a github-windows protocol using that way. So it's likely that there IS a way available to make it work with chrome. Sadly, right now, I can't dig further into it as the Application doesn't want to react on any browser.

Comment: When launching using chrome, it asks `Do you want to launch test.bat?`... Is there any way to change where it says `test.bat` into `My Program` so that it reads: `Do you want to launch My Program?`?

Comment: It would always be what you make the executable. You would need to change the bath to the batch file to the one you want to use. It's the last line of the reg. The `$1` would be the argument which would be the whole "url" you called.

Comment: Ok, the reason I asked was that in Microsoft Edge, when you open an `xbox` link, it asks: `DID YOU MEAN TO SWITCH APPS? "Microsoft Edge" is trying to launch "Xbox Gaming"` and I was wondering how it set the name.

Comment: any idea how that works?

Comment: Not really. I don't have the XBOX app installed (only Windows 7) but you could just have a look at `HKCR` and look for an xbox protocol. Searching from the top of `HKCR` should work. You could use F3 to jump to the next hit. Also check the Edge Addons/Plugins to see whenever they just register a Addon/Plugin. I haven't done any further digging as the integration simply doesn't work on my system in any kind of browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Program Setup]
Add the subkey to your application  "SupportedProtocols"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

Next add a Str Type with the name of each Protocol you want your program to handle, with no values

[Application Setup]
Next add/update your application's entry under
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\

*If your application needs to save the URL, do the following:
Add a Str Type named "SaveURL"

*If your application needs to use the URL, do the following:
Add a DWORD Type named "UseURL"
Set it's value to 1

The above should enable support for your application